# Post array with multiple same input names

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Im having a form that posts an array (`invoice[]`) of company and invoice items.

My form got some inputs with the same name and i want to push them into the array and post them to the database as one row for each item. How can i push the items in `item[0], item[1]...etc`, in the same array to store it properly in the database ?

This is the input group that is been repeated in my form:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="checkall">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-5">
        <textarea type="text" name="invoice[description]" class="form-control" id="description" rows="1" value="{{invdtl_itemDescription}}"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="number" name="invoice[unit]" class="form-control" id="unit" maxlength="5" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="number" name="invoice[qty]" class="form-control" id="qty" maxlength="5" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="number" name="invoice[price]" class="form-control" id="price" maxlength="5" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="number" name="invoice[discount]" class="form-control" id="discount" maxlength="5" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="number" name="invoice[discountPrice]" class="form-control" id="discountPrice" maxlength="5" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="number" name="invoice[total]" class="form-control" id="total" maxlength="5" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="number" name="invoice[vat]" class="form-control" id="vat" value="23" maxlength="3" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The array is posted with `$.ajax` to the database in two tables (one for `invoice_header` and one for `invoice_details`. Invoice items (the one that is been repeated in the form) should be stored in the `invoice_details` each row at a time.

Form data:

```
invoice[client]: 1
invoice[type]: receipt
invoice[invoice]: 155
invoice[date]: 2014-07-07
invoice[shipmethod]: 1
===== Item #1 =====
invoice[description]: Test
invoice[unit]: 1
invoice[qty]: 1
invoice[price]: 1
invoice[discount]: 1
invoice[discountPrice]: 1
invoice[total]: 1
invoice[vat]: 23
===== Item #2 =====
invoice[description]: Test 2
invoice[unit]: 2
invoice[qty]: 2
invoice[price]: 2
invoice[discount]: 2
invoice[discountPrice]: 2
invoice[total]: 2
invoice[vat]: 23
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No it isn't. I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: Ι updated the question with question-mark for those who didnt get my question. I've tried to loop the `invoice[description],invoice[unit]...` but i cant get the array in a proper form, or store it properly in the database for each item. I've tried js librarys (like form2js - https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js) with no sucess)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593914/php-change-all-keys-and-convert-key-to-value

Comment: Not very helpfull. I use `flourish` framework and has better coding, than this

Comment: I manage to solve it but i cant store the invoice items (from array) to seperate rows in db. I only get the last cause it overides the data. I should look into `flourish` documentation now. Thanks anyway